# Translate the SQL statement in to Qlikview expression

Tags: sql, expression, qlikview

Currently im trying to code a expression but I only know how to query it in SQl statement

SQL:

```
select * from Orders o
where o.product_name != MBProductName 
AND
o.transaction_id in 
(
select m.transaction_id from marketBasket m where m.product_name = MBProductName);
```

I want to put the results into a chart of table form.

And it will do this query when I select the MBProductName.

can anyone help me translate? Thanks in advance

My Scripts:

```
LOAD  
 Customer_ID, 
 Customer_Country, 
 Customer_Gender, 
 Customer_BirthDate, 
 Customer_Age_Group, 
 Customer_Type, 
 Customer_Age, 
 Real_age, 
 Continent, 
 Country_Name


Orders:
LOAD  
 Customer_ID, 
 Employee_ID, 
 Street_ID, 
 Order_Date, 
 Delivery_Date, 
 Order_ID As %%MarketBasket, 
 Order_ID,
 Order_Type, 
 Product_ID, 
 Quantity, 
 Total_Retail_Price, 
 CostPrice_Per_Unit, 
 Discount, 
 Profit_per_Product, 
 PrfitRange, 
 ProfitMarginRange


Products:
LOAD Product_ID, 
 Product_Line, 
 Product_Category, 
 Product_Group, 
 Product_Name, 
 Supplier_Country, 
 Supplier_Name

TmpMarketBasket:
Load
%%MarketBasket AS TmpOrderId,
Product_ID AS TmpProductId,
Order_Date As TmpOrderDate
Resident Orders;

LEFT JOIN
Load 
Product_ID AS TmpProdcutId,
Product_Name AS TmpProductName,
Product_Line AS TmpProductLine,
Product_Category As TmpProductCategory,
Product_Group As TmpProductGroup
Resident Products;

MarketBasket:
LOAD
TmpOrderId                 as %%MarketBasket,
TmpProductName            as MBProductName,
TmpProductGroup             as MBProductGroup
RESIDENT TmpMarketBasket;

DROP TABLE TmpMarketBasket;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how the `MarketBasket` table is populated (perhaps you could provide an example of some data from it), however, you could create a straight table with your required fields and then use the following expression for the quantity total:

```
=sum({$<Product_Name-={$(=GetFieldSelections(MBProductName))}>} Quantity)
```

What this does is to take the selection you made on `MBProductName` and then exclude it from the values in `Product_Name` during the summation of the `Quantity` field. As entries where `Product_Name = MBProductName` will sum to zero, these will be supressed from the table.

Comment: thanks for your reply the MarketBasket table have 3 columns : %%MarketBasket(order_ID),MBProductName(ProductName),MBProductGroup(Product_Group)